# Add a maven dependency to SBT project

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sbt-plugin, sbt-revolver

I am trying to reference a maven project dependency in my `build.sbt` file. I understand I need to add an additional `resolver` to my file since the project is hosted in an internal artifactory store

```
build.sbt

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.4",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4",
  "com.<companyname>" %% "<libraryname>" % "2.3.0"
)

resolvers += "<library name>" at "http://artifactory.<internal url>.io:80/dsc-mvn"
```

However, it turns out that SBT ends up searching for a path that has `_2.11` version appended to it. This is the error message that I see in IntelliJ

```
[info] Loading settings for project sbt-demo from build.sbt ...
[warn] Discarding 1 session setting.  Use 'session save' to persist session settings.
[info] Set current project to SparkExample (in build file:<project_path>)
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions
[info] The new value will be used by Global / ssOptions
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to SparkExample (in build file:<project_path>)
[info] Updating ...
[warn]  module not found: com.<companyname>#<libraryname>_2.11;2.3.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/vshah/.ivy2/local/com.<companyname>/<libraryname>_2.11/2.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/<companyname>/<libraryname>_2.11/2.3.0/<libraryname>_2.11-2.3.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/vshah/.sbt/preloaded/com.<companyname>/<libraryname>_2.11/2.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/vshah/.sbt/preloaded/com/<companyname>/<libraryname>_2.11/2.3.0/<libraryname>_2.11-2.3.0.pom
[warn] ==== <libraryname>: tried
[warn]   http://artifactory.<internal url>.io:80/dsc-mvn/com/<companyname>/<libraryname>_2.11/2.3.0/<libraryname>_2.11-2.3.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.<companyname>#<libraryname>_2.11;2.3.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
```

Invalid Path (as the project is trying to search above)- 
`http://artifactory.<internal url>.io/dsc-mvn/com/<companyname>/<libraryname>_2.11/2.3.0/<libraryname>_2.11-2.3.0.pom`

Valid path - 
`http://artifactory.<internal url>.io/dsc-mvn/com/<companyname>/<libraryname>/2.3.0/<libraryname>_2.11-2.3.0.pom`

My question is how do I let SBT know that I am referencing a maven project at the above mentioned valid path?

Comment: If you want to ad a **Java** dependency just use a single `%` between the organization and the name of the dependency. The double `%%` tells sbt to automatically add the scala version to the end of the name of the dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
"com.<companyname>" % "<libraryname>" % "2.3.0"
```

The `%%` in the definition automatically appends the project scala version to the library name. Check out the [official sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

refer to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt to get the right Build tool for your project, and kindly check if the version in the dependency matches the version of your scala .

Can you please tell me more about the kind of dependency you need?